# Edit text file in IPython terminal without switching terminal

Tags: python, ipython

I want to conveniently open a file in a IPython terminal without switching to another terminal outside IPython. Specifically, can I open vim or other common text editors in a IPython terminal?

Comment: What's the problem with opening another terminal? Or using an IDE?

Comment: No problem with another terminal. Would be great if I can directly open a file content at the iPython terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%edit` command:

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-edit

> Usage: `%edit [options] [args]`
>
> `%edit` runs IPython’s editor hook. The
>   default version of this hook is set to call the editor specified by
>   your `$EDITOR` environment variable. If this isn’t found, it will
>   default to vi under Linux/Unix and to notepad under Windows. See the
>   end of this docstring for how to change the editor hook.

Comment: Nice! But how to set up the $EDITOR variable?

Comment: $EDITOR is an environment variable, which in `bash` shell (the default shell for most UNIX/Linux environments), can be set with `export EDITOR=vim` in the command line.

Comment: I use "edit test.ipynb" to call vim to open it. But isn't any syntax coloring in the file's content? All are black and white.

Comment: The default editor is vi, which does not have any syntax highlighting feature. Have you tried setting $EDITOR to vim instead using the command I showed you above?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `!vim myfile.py` inside ipython.
`!`, like in VIm, is allowing you to run external commands.